# How do I locate a Windows Workgroup/Domain

Tags: windows, domain

I am the administrator of a fairly large laptop program. When browsing my Windows network, I notice an old Windows Domain name and several workgroups.

How do I locate these extra workgroup/domains and expunge them from the system?

The domain in particular was decommissioned four years ago.  There is nothing here that should be supporting that name, in fact there are no computers still around that used that domain name.

Comment: "I am the administrator" > Try serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
NETSTAT -a <machine-name-in-old-domain>
```

to find out where it thinks it's workgroup name server or browse master is located to narrow down where to look. That at the least will allow you to see the name table.

The Microsoft kb article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188305 also gives troubleshooting steps and tools for these problems.

Answer (score 1):

I feel sure that the community can solve this, but can you provide more information?  Where do you see this list?  Windows Explorer, Net View, NBTSTAT -c

Would NBTSTAT -R help note capital R help.
How about locating the Microsoft Browser Service and disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to scan your network. Some useful products are:

[Free IP Scanner 1.6](http://www.eusing.com/ipscan/free_ip_scanner.htm)
[Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home)

Just to remark that these ghost networks might not be caused by real physical machines:
You might have some virtual machines hanging around that still think that these exist.